# informatica repository service unable to enable

Tags: repository, informatica, informatica-powercenter, dac, informatica-cloud

I am having issues enabling the repository service on the Informatica Admin console. Steps I took so far,

1. create a new repository service with option to create contents, keeps spinning and after a while it times out. I log back in and I see the repository service created in the Admins console with option to disable but unavailable. Also not able to see the repository tables created in the metadata schema. And not able to connect using the powercenter repository manager as well.
2. create a new repository service without create contents. A disabled repository service is created. To add/restore contents I try to enable the service then it keeps spinning and nothing happens. After a while it times out and when I log back in I see the option to disable but the service is unavailable. Therefore I am unable to add contents.

I am looking for some helpful insight to resolve this crisis.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the log say? Could be all kinds of reasons..

Answer (score 0):

While creating repository did you provide database user name and password? And that user has necessary privileges to be a user of informatica repository?
User of that database must have necessary privileges. Even if you have error in the credentials provided during the creation, repository will be created as it can be created at any time in informatica. Kindly delete the repository and create the new one by providing accurate credentials. 
Execute these queries to improve the visibility of the user to informatica,
increase the cursor size,

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET OPEN_CURSOR = 1000 SCOPE = BOTH;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW, SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO USER_NAME;
```

Make sure you are executing these queries in sys user.

In case you need to clear the issue without deleting the created repository, go to,
Actions -> Repository contents -> Create